# Problems with cell ranges and vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a converter Hex to Binary in Excel. 
I used the Vlookup in Vba, but it doesn't work as i expect, 
because in the cell i have "0000", but only one 0 is written by the function.
How can I solve this problem?

`Cells(8, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("G7"), Range("U6:V21"), 2)`

Comment: Is this just to demonstrate the use of VLookup? If you actually want to convert hex to binary there are easier ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the format of the cell to text in order to get a text result to stick:

```
Cells(8, 7).NumberFormat = "@" 'text
Cells(8, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("G7"), Range("U6:V21"), 2)
```

Comment: @KingRoy you show your thanks by marking as correct if this answered the question.